# HTML - How do I use a popup in order to input and output a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I see this pattern used very often!

- Click on a link
- popup appears with a form
- fill in form and submit
- popup closes and main page populates itself with the form's data.

---

**Any idea how this works?**

### Edit:

by popup I mean an actual window popup, rather than a modal window. A modal window could work nicely though I reckon.

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript prompt for a single value? Or a modal dialog for multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is with Javascript. Django's own admin includes a (fairly clunky) example: when you save the popup, it returns a response consisting of just a `<script>` tag containing Javascript which references the box in the parent form. See for example `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.response_add`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this ?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html

You can validate the form with js / jquery and then do an ajax call and post the data to the server

Comment: awesome. It's not what I really meant, but this could work great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use somethign like [facebox](http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/) to create the popup. This requests a page to the server (your form). Once submitted, detect that the facebox was closed (see the API) and make a new ajax request to the server that will return the needed data to populate your page.